# Matrix Inversion in CBLAS/LAPACK vs Python

Tags: numpy, matrix, lapack, matrix-inverse, cblas

The matrix I am trying to invert is:

```
    [ 1  0  1]
A = [ 2  0  1]
    [-1  1  1]
```

The true inverse is:

```
       [-1  1  0]
A^-1 = [-3  2  1]
       [ 2 -1  0]
```

Using Python's numpy.linalg.inv, I get the correct answer. One of my routines for matrix inverse uses dgetri_, it is:

```
void compute_matrix_inverse_dbl( double* matrix,
                                 int order,
                                 double * inverse )
{

    int N, lwork;
    int success;
    int *pivot;
    double* workspace;

    //===Allocate Space===//
    pivot = malloc(order * order * order * sizeof(*pivot));
    workspace = malloc(order * order * sizeof(*workspace));

    //===Run Setup===//
    N = order;
    copy_array_dbl(matrix, order*order, inverse);
    lwork = order*order;

    //===Factor Matrix===//
    dgetrf_(&N,&N,inverse,&N,pivot,&success);

    //===Compute Inverse===//
    dgetri_(&N, inverse, &N, pivot, workspace, &lwork, &success);

    //===Clean Up===//
    free(workspace);
    free(pivot);

    return;
  }
```

Using this routine, I get:

```
       [-1   1 +-e1 ]
A^-1 = [-3   2   1  ]
       [ 2  -1 +-e2 ]
```

Where e1 and e2 and small numbers on the order of machine precision 1e-16. Now perhaps dgetri_ is not the best to use. However, when I invert using QR decomposition via zgeqrf_ and zungqr_, I get a similar answer. When I use dgesvd_ for inverse using SVD, I get a similar answer as well.

Python seems to use a routine called _umath_linalg.inv. So I have a few questions:

- What does that routine do?
- What CBLAS/LAPACK routine can I use to invert this matrix and get a result like CBLAS/LAPACK (such that the e1 and e2 get replaced by proper zeros)?

Comment: You need to use `?GESV` or `?GESVX` for the inverses with full precision not with decomposition based solvers. LU is faster but as you see loses precision. Scipy `linalg.solve` has recently switched to  `___x` routines for condition number checks.

Comment: Also never ever use matrix inverse unless you need to refer to it. For matrix algebra always use solve.

Comment: @percusse I'm not sure what you mean by ____x algorithms. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I mean GESVX, POSVX,HESVX and so on

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [`numpy.linalg.inv`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.1/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L468-L533) is a lite version of the [scipy.linalg.inv](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/linalg/basic.py#L907-L979) as per the description:

> This module is a lite version of the linalg.py module in SciPy which
>   contains high-level Python interface to the LAPACK library.

Looking at [scipy.linalg.inv](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/linalg/basic.py#L907-L979), it does a call to `getrf`, then `getri`.